# How to count character values from one dataframe and add to another existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two existing `pandas` dataframes.  One dataframe is a list of approximately 1000 words.  This is the head of that dataframe:

```
0
0   abase
1   abate
2   abdicate
3   abduct
4   aberration
```

My second dataframe is an empty dataframe with 26 rows and columns corresponding to the letters of the alphabet:

```
End     a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   ...     q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
Start                                                                                   
    a   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    b   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    c   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    d   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    e   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    f   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    g   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    h   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    i   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    j   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    k   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    l   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    m   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    n   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    o   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    p   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    q   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    r   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    s   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    t   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    u   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    v   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    w   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    x   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    y   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    z   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

For each word in the first dataframe, I'm supposed to discern what letters they start and end with, and then add 1 to the corresponding row and column in the empty dataframe.

For example: `abase` starts with 'a' and ends with 'e'.  So, I would need to add 1 to the location where e and a meet on the empty dataframe.  I need to do this systematically throughout the entire first dataframe, but I'm stuck.

I tried using startswith and ends with:

`values = (input[0].str.startswith(r'a') & input[0].str.endswith(r'e'))`

That returns me a `true` or `false` value correctly, but I don't know how to use those boolean values to add to my empty dataframe.

What's the best course of action?  I'm not allowed to use any libraries other than `string`, `numpy`, and `pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the string methods to get the 1st and last character then perhaps `crosstab`, or `pivot` or `groupby`. `crosstab` is slower, but the syntax is nice.

#### Create your base table:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

l = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
df_base = (pd.DataFrame(index=l, columns=l).fillna(0)
             .rename_axis('Start', axis=0)
             .rename_axis('End', axis=1))
```

#### Code:

```
df = df.assign(Start=df[0].str[0], End=df[0].str[-1])
to_add = pd.crosstab(df.Start, df.End)
#to_add = df.pivot_table(index='Start', columns='End', aggfunc='size')
#to_add = df.groupby(['Start', 'End']).size().unstack(-1)

#End    e  n  t
#Start         
#a      3  1  1

df_base = df_base.add(to_add, fill_value=0)
```

#### Output (first 5 rows):

```
End      a    b    c    d    e    f  ...    x    y    z  
Start                                                                      
a      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  3.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
b      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
c      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
d      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
e      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

Though in this case there is no need for `df_base` and you could instead `reindex` twice:

```
(to_add.reindex(list(string.ascii_lowercase), axis=1)
       .reindex(list(string.ascii_lowercase), axis=0)
     .fillna(0))
```

Comment: I constantly am checking my work, but every time I run the above code, the sums accumulate instead of resetting each time.  How can I edit the code so that it is not a cumulative sum?  (Edit) -  I figured it out.  Thanks!